# How can I make a mobile website look good both on iPhone 4 (Retina Screen) and Android phones?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mobile-website, retina-display, android-browser

This mobile website:
http://www.tomorroworld.com/instarea/

Looks good both on iPhone 4 (Retina Screen) and regular iPhone screens. But on Android phones, it's too much zoomed in. How can I fix this easily?

This is what the `viewport` tag looks like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640,initial-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=0.5,user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: Did you try many browsers in the Android ? try Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I want it to look good in the default Browser app.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting your widths to be based on percentages rather than pixels and then let them scale down in smaller devices. You could also add in some media queries for additional layout control at smaller sizes.

Using viewport as you have is essentially hard-coding your page width at 320px for all mobile devices - works great for older iphones but not for many other devices.